# Running GPU on multiple PyTorch tensor operators

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I have the following PyTorch tensor:

```
X = np.array([[1, 3, 2, 3], [2, 3, 5, 6]])
X = torch.FloatTensor(X).cuda()
```

I was wondering if there is any difference (especially in the speed) between Scenario A or B below if I run the following multiple PyTorch operators in one line?

Scenario A:

```
X_sq_sum = (X**2).cuda().sum(dim = 1).cuda()
```

Scenario B:

```
X_sq_sum = (X**2).sum(dim = 1).cuda()
```

ie. Scenario A has two `.cuda()` whereas Scenario B only has one `.cuda()`.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will perform equally as the CUDA conversion is only done once.

As described in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.cuda), repeated `.cuda()` calls will be no-ops if the object is already in CUDA memory.

Comment: Thanks @Dario Sučić. Does that mean since I have called `cuda()` at the top in `X = torch.FloatTensor(X).cuda()`, so that means in the operators, I don't have to have any `cuda()`, ie. I can just have `X_sq_sum = (X**2).sum(dim = 1)` and this line of code will still use GPU?

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much it. Once you call `.cuda()` on your tensor it is converted to a CUDA tensor, and (most) subsequent operations will be done on the GPU.